# Conexão SQL Server - Python

Tags: sql, python, api, sintaxe, conexão

Boa tarde galera estou com dificuldades em fazer uma conexão com sql, sempre que tento fazer a conexão o seguinte erro ocorre:

```
('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (2)')
  File "C:\Users\ytalos\Documents\Ytalo\Projeto1\Conexão.py", line 15, in conectar_com_banco
    conexao = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
  File "C:\Users\ytalos\Documents\Ytalo\Projeto1\Conexão.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor=conectar_com_banco('DW')
```

Queria realizar a autenticação do database com as credenciais do Windows.

Nome do Banco:  DW
 
Servidor: X

```
def conectar_com_banco(usuario):
    if usuario in 'DW':
        server = 'X' 
        database = 'dw' 
        username = 'teste' 
        password = 'teste1'
     else: 
        print('funcao_nao_encontrado')
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cur=cnxn.cursor()
    return(cur)
cursor=conectar_com_banco('DW')
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
print(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a string de conexão desta maneira:

```
params_conn = 'Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};' \
              'Server={servidor}, {porta};' \
              'Database={base};' \
              'UID={usuario};' \
              'PWD={senha};'
```

Para conectar, você deverá criar a string de conexão com os parâmetros acima listados da seguinte maneira:

```
str_conexao = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % urllib.parse.quote_plus(params_conn.format(servidor='X', porta=123, base='minha-base', usuario='user', senha='senha'))
```

Perceba o uso do `mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s` para compor a string de conexão. Indica que quero usar o `pyodbc` (deve instalar na sua máquina) juntamente com o driver ODBC (que aparentemente você já tem instalado). Caso não tenha instalado, siga a instruções [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) da própria Microsoft que ensina como fazer.

Você também precisa fazer o `urllib.parse.quote_plus()` para realizar o encode necessário dos caracteres especiais usados na string de conexão.

É isso. Caso ainda não consiga fazer a conexão, certifique-se de que está tudo corretamente instalado (`ODBC`e `pyodbc`) e também se o servidor é acessível ou disponível, ou mesmo usuário e senhas estão corretos.

Para acessar a base de dados usando as credenciais do windows, você pode usar o parâmetro `Trusted_Connection=yes;` e não será necessário utilizar `UID` nem `PWD`.

Comment: Teria como usar usuário e senha do windows como autenticação na conexão?

Comment: Sim, em vez de usuário e senha você pode removê-los e apenas adicionar o parâmetro `Trusted_Connection=yes;`. Editei minha resposta para contemplar sua dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Igor :)